# Lagrange Multipliers Formulation

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Suppose we have the following problem: $$ \text{minimize } \ f(x) \\ \text{subject to } \ Ax = b$$

How do we know whether to write the Lagrangian Dual as $$  \text{minimize } f(x) + \lambda(Ax-b)$$ versus $$  \text{minimize } f(x) + \lambda(b-Ax)?$$

Answer (score 1):

We don't, and it does not matter. The  $\lambda$ you are going to find will change sign. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Comment: Then why is that in minimization problems I see equality constraints $Ax = b$ being written as $Ax-b$ but in maximization problems it is written as $b-Ax$? In a minimization problem I could write it as $b-Ax$?

Comment: So no matter how you write it....you will get the same solution? One may be easier to solve than the other?

Comment: When you minimize, $(x, \lambda)$ is variable. In one case you'll get $(x_0,\lambda_0)$ as a solution, in the other case $(x_0,-\lambda_0)$. You are interested in $x_0$. The solution is the same, yes. (And both problems are equally difficult).